# FLAC Recording from iPhone not getting Converted Using Google Speech API

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder, google-speech-api, flac, laravel-5.7

I have Configured `AVAudioRecorder` as below to record Audio in Flac Format

**Recorder Configuration**

```
let settings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatFLAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            ]
```

**Recording Session**

```
recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.allowBluetooth,.defaultToSpeaker])
```

Files Record Successfully and Played well in Device and also successfully Uploaded to backend Services.

**Issue** Some audio file do not get converted using `Google Speech API`

----> **Issues From Google Speech API**

1. File Doesn't contain FLAC header
2. soxi FAIL formats: can't open input file `636737069431546112.flac': FLAC ERROR whilst decoding metadata

Comment: Did you fixed the problem ?